# How to add tag to docker push command from docker-compose.yml in github actions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I am trying to push a docker image to docker hub when there is a change to the docker-compose.yml file (New major version, change image tag). The build runs fine, but when I try to push, I don't have access to the image name, to it defaults to the tag `latest`, which is not what I just built.

```
- name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker compose build
    
- name: Docker push
      run: docker push ${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}/myreponame
```

I get the error

```
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/***/myreponame]
tag does not exist: ***/myreponame:latest
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I need to somehow get the tag or full image name from the docker-compose.yml file:

`docker push ${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}}/myreponame:{tag_from_file}`

Is there a way to get this data in the docker compose build command, or from the file? I don't want to manually enter data to CI/CD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add use variable substitution into your docker-compose file for your image name like:

```yaml
myapp:
  image: "${REPO}/myreponame:${tag_from_file}"
```

And build with `REPO` and `tag_from_file` defined as env vars:

```yaml
- name: Build the Docker image
  run: REPO=${{secrets.DOCKER_USER}} tag_from_file=something docker compose build
```

And it should work.

You can also use the Github action made by Docker to build and push your image: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images